# trying to use a variable that was created in a function in other parts of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to return a variable that was made inside a function that is in a parameter of a resize event in jQuery. The variable should be updated every time the user resizes the page. I would like to use the variable to make the width of a div ('.slide'). So Every time the user resizes the browser I want the .slide element to have the width of the browser.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
        var windowwidth = $(window).outerWidth();
        return windowwidth;
    })
```

I want to use windowwidth

```
//To make each slide the width of the window 
var slideWidth = $('.slide').css("width", windowwidth)
```

I will use slideWidth here

```
$('.slide').css('width', slideWidth);
```

I may want to use windowwidth other places

I tried using width 100% but I couldn't float left images that were 100%. I was trying to make a slide show that took up the whole width of the page.

[Broken fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jack2ky/JLHQB/)

Guys thanks for the answers but some that I am seeing don't demonstrate how I could use the width in other parts of the code. you only show the resize part. but there is another part, moveSlide() that is not getting the width in most answer. Its not reusable is what im seeing in most of the answers so far.

Comment: Why are you declaring it 2 times? once global and inside function!

Comment: I was testing to see if by declaring it globally would sove the problem. but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for, you don't need to declare `slideWidth` globally. Use `$(window).width()` to find current window width on resize. Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLHQB/29/).

Comment: thanks for your effort. this looks the best but when I make the pannel in jsFiddle bigger the images appear to go in multiple lines. there should be only one line of images and one image should appear on the screen at a time. If you can fix it when you get a chance that would be great

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update holder width on resize. I updated link to the fiddle in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for fixing it. I just want to see more responses from others before accepting an answer.FYI

Answer (score 1):

You have to make `windowwidth` **globally** like

```
var windowwidth=$(window).outerWidth();
$(window).resize(function(){
    windowwidth = $(window).outerWidth();
    //return windowwidth;
    demo();
});
function demo()
{
    var slideWidth = $('.slide').css("width", windowwidth)
    slides.wrapAll('<div id = "slideHolder"></div>')
    slides.css({"float" : "left"});
    // var bodywidth = $('body').outerWidth();
    // var windowwidth = $(window).outerWidth()
    $('.slide').css('width', slideWidth);
    $("#slideHolder").css("width", slideWidth * numberOfSlides );
}
demo();
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLHQB/8/)

Comment: thanks, can you demo how I could i get the slideWidth in the moveslide function to work. the moveslide is called by changePosition() and the change position is used by the set interval.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var windowwidth = $(window).outerWidth();
    return windowwidth;
})
```

here windowwidth will be in the scope of the function and then the value will be return.

It isnt setting it on the global scope for access elsewhere.

you could try

```
window.windowwidth =  $(window).outerWidth();
```

To get it on the global scope

Answer (score 0):

for that just make a global variable instead of making a local variable inside the function!

or you can use localStorage to save the perticular width like below:-

```
$.localStorage( 'foo', {data:'bar'} );

$.localStorage( 'foo' );
```

Answer (score 0):

[working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLHQB/10/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var windowwidth = $(window).outerWidth();
```

You have to make the variable `windowwidth` global, and initialize it with the actual window with in the `$(document).ready` function. 
Note that you then must remove the `var` in front of the windowwith in the `$(window).resize` function. Otherwise you use a local variable there, which can't be used outside the function.

Comment: thanks for your answer but im a lil confused. if you see in the code i use slidewidth in like 3 other places how do I get the updating width for those scenarios

Answer (score 0):

You declared `windowWidth` to be in the scope of a function, and then you're trying to access it in the global scope which won't work. You'll have to declare `windowWidth` in the global scope and use it within the function.

I also had to do the same to `slideWidth` to get your demo to work, you can see it in action here:

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JLHQB/3/)

Comment: thanks for the answer but can you please tell me why it appears that slideWidth var in the moveSlide function doesnt pick up the width. It should animate margin left the width * the position..

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your variable in a global scope

```
var windowwidth=0;

$(window).resize(function(){
        windowwidth = $(window).outerWidth();
        return windowwidth;
    })
```